# How to fix scrapes and a small dent from other car

Tags: paint-scratches, accident

When I pulled into my drive I accidentally scraped the side of my wife's car and now there is a black line down it and some marks near the Fender. As well as a dent in my car. What is the best way to go about fixing these

Comment: The marks, are they scratched in or is it from some kind of rubber trim from your car? You can try pulling out the dent with a strong suction cup, if its not too small. Or if you are able to get to it from behind you can try to pop it back from the other side. If its on the bumper and if its plastic use warm water to make the bumper soft and you can pop it back in place.

Answer (score 1):

Put a little of brake fluid on a clean clotch, and wipe gently the paint scratch.

The brake fluid will disolve the paint, and spread it to hide the scrape, if you overdo it you will damage your car paint.

Do it at your own risk.

Comment: This is a fair answer, but I think I would start with 3M "Finesse" and a cotton tee shirt before I resorted to brake fluid.  I know what you suggest can work, just like Methadone may break a heroin habit.  The 3M products might be a bit safer, albeit requiring more "elbow grease".  Good answer nonetheless.  Thank you for contributing and joining the community!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are but there are companies who specialise in simple dent / chip repair such as this one in the UK : https://www.chipsaway.co.uk/

Comment: I think he wants a "DIY" way of doing so. But that is just a guess